# How to mock static method with same parameters differently in a test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

This seems highly unlikely, but is there a way I could mock a static method in a certain way and the second time in another way?

A case scenario -

```
if(StringUtils.isEmpty("")) {
   throw Exception();
}
...
if(StringUtils.isEmpty("")) {
   doSomething();
}
```

The test is written in following way.

```
mockStatic(StringUtils.class);
when(StringUtils.isEmpty("")).thenReturn(false);
/*Is it possible to make this behaviour run only once such that second time
when it is called we can mock it again.*/
limitStaticMock(times(1));//Is this possible?
when(StringUtils.isEmpty("")).thenReturn(true);//Setting behaviour again.
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be altering what amounts to a pure function. Assuming your string ultimately comes from a parameter, run with differing parameters in different test cases.

Comment: @chrylis But, to make it a true unit test, shouldn't I mock any external dependencies and StringUtils is from another framework (apache.commons)

Comment: No, you should only mock external behavior *that can change*, such as the response from a database call. You wouldn't mock `1 + 2`. The use of `StringUtils` rather than an inline check (or, for example, using Groovy's `asBoolean`) is an implementation detail. Test the different cases--`""` will never be anything but empty.

Comment: @chrylis Got ya. I found a link related to what you said. [Mocking Objects in FP](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3565760/4669984)

Comment: Thanks for the quick acceept!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use *mocking* to control such "internals".

You can easily control what your code under test is doing by controlling the string value that gets to that static call. You want the test to give true; then write a test that pushes in an empty string; and that expects an exception.

You have another production code method that shouldn't throw - then write up another test; and do the necessary setup.

But do **not** start mocking such methods. If you think you have to, then your design is not testable; in other words: broken! Fix your design, instead of using the big mocking hammer!